# context processor: how to write login and signup in all views

Tags: django

I created a view for Login/Signup/Forget Password (5 forms in single view). I need these forms in header so I added links in base.html and extended in all templates. How can I make this view available for all templates.

```
def master_link(request):
    login_form = UserLoginForm()
    send_otp_form = SendOTPForm()
    verify_otp_form = VerifyOTPForm()
    registration_form = RegistrationForm()
    forget_password_form = ForgetPasswordForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'login_submit' in request.POST:
        login_form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)

        if login_form.is_valid():
            user = login_form.login(request)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'send_otp_submit' in request.POST:
        send_otp_form = SendOTPForm(request.POST)

        if send_otp_form.is_valid():
            mobile_number = send_otp_form.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
            type_otp = send_otp_form.cleaned_data['type']
            otp = random.randint(1000, 9999)
            otpobj = sendotp.sendotp.sendotp(settings.AUTH_KEY, str(otp) + ' keep otp with you.')
            otpobj.send(mobile_number, 'TestOTP', otp)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('verify_otp', args=(mobile_number, type_otp)))

    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'signup_submit' in request.POST:
        registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registration_form.is_valid():
            user = registration_form.save(commit=False)
            mobile_number = registration_form.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
            user.username = registration_form.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
            password = registration_form.cleaned_data['password']
            gender = request.POST.get('inlineRadioOptions')
            user.gender = gender
            user.mobile_number = mobile_number
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=mobile_number, password=password)
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'forget_password_submit' in request.POST:
        forget_password_form = ForgetPasswordForm(request.POST)
        if forget_password_form.is_valid():
            password = forget_password_form.cleaned_data['password']
            mobile_number = forget_password_form.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
            user = User.objects.get(mobile_number=mobile_number)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        verify_otp_form = VerifyOTPForm(request.POST)
        if verify_otp_form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))

    # SportsMaster
    sports_data = SportsMaster.objects.all()

    context = {
        'login_form': login_form,
        'send_otp_form': send_otp_form,
        'verify_otp_form': verify_otp_form,
        'registration_form': registration_form,
        'forget_password_form': forget_password_form,
        'sports_data':sports_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'user_front/user_login.html', context)
```

I can't write these functions in all views. I know I can use context processor to send variables in all templates but how can I use these functions in all views. Also I have 3 apps and I have to send these variables only in 1 app.

Comment: How does this look like in the first place? Every page on your website contains all of these forms, visible to the user at all times? Or does the user first have to click on a "login" button in the header which then displays the form?

Comment: user have to click a login button. Everything is in popup modal.@dirkgroten

Comment: then fetch the modal content with javascript (ajax call) by calling this view. Also submit using javascript.

Comment: @dirkgroten,thanks I am going to try this.